# Python scripts works in IDLE but not as a .desktop icon

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, icons, python-idle

I am trying to run a python3 script on icon (.desktop) click from an LX desktop environment.  It worked before, but now for some reason it wasn't opening, but still working in IDLE3.  So, I typed in "python3 oldtext.py" into the terminal and **got these errors:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "oldtext.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/tkinter.py", line 13, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 7, in <module>
    from six.moves import tkinter_filedialog as FileDialog
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 89, in __get__
result = self._resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 108, in _resolve
return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 79, in _import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named 'tkinter.filedialog'; 'tkinter' is not a package
```

But it (tkinter) is already installed when I try to install it...

Since it says import error, **here are my imports**:

```
#/usr/bin/env python3
#import necessary packages
from tkinter import *
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import time
import io
import os
import serial
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import sys
import random
```

Also, **here is the .desktop file.**  (I did make the script executable)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GUI DESKTOP
Exec=/home/pi/Desktop/oldtext.py
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/idle.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Development;
StartupNotify=true
```

What is going on here?  I am assuming these errors are what is causing the file not to open upon icon click.  Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that in your error, it says:

```
  File "oldtext.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/tkinter.py", line 13, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
```

The second part, `File "/home/pi/Desktop/tkinter.py"`, is the important part. It shows that the `tkinter` module has been overriden by another file. And, line 13 of this file is `from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg`, which is incidentally also line 13 of the code you pasted in your question. My guess is that your file is named `tkinter.py` and you need to rename it for your script to work.

Comment: Yep.  That was it... I feel super dumb now.  I had no clue that something like that could happen!  Thanks for your quick answer!